# Why does the cell style index returning wrong CellFormat value when parsing excel cells using OpenXml SDK?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Consider a General format cell having a value of 39.95. When I fetch the CellFormat of the cell it returns wrong cell format-

```
CellFormat thisCellFormat = ((CellFormat)cellFmts.ChildElements[(int)thisCell.StyleIndex.Value]);
int fmtId = Convert.ToInt32(thisCellFormat.FormatId.Value);
```

The value of fmtId returned is 1, and in some cases 38, where it should be 2 or 39.

This issue is only for General format cells, I am getting correct id for Number format cells.

Below is the [Standard ECMA-376 Office Open XML File Formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) specified set of implied cell formats for reference-

ID  Format Code
0   General
1   0
2   0.00
3   #,##0
4   #,##0.00
9   0%
10  0.00%
11  0.00E+00
12  # ?/?
13  # ??/??
14  mm-dd-yy
15  d-mmm-yy
16  d-mmm
17  mmm-yy
18  h:mm AM/PM
19  h:mm:ss AM/PM
20  h:mm
21  h:mm:ss
22  m/d/yy h:mm
37  #,##0 ;(#,##0)
38  #,##0 ;Red
39  #,##0.00;(#,##0.00)
40  #,##0.00;Red
45  mm:ss
46  [h]:mm:ss
47  mmss.0
48  ##0.0E+0
49  @

Comment: @pnuts using the system separators, . for decimal and , for thousands.

Comment: Answer for the question comes with how Spreadsheet styles are applied to cells

Comment: @KCdod The spreadsheet is created using Excel, not OpenXML SDK. And I tried with very basic spreadsheet having just one cell of General format with a decimal value. Still gives the wrong FormatID

Comment: What is the value of `thisCellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formats you are talking about are defined as styles and when Cell is created style index is set accordingly using style index. The `number format` is embedded inside these styles by referring `NumberFormatId`

Ex : Making CellFormats in Open XML , note difference

```
   CellFormat cellformat0 = new CellFormat() { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }; // default                        
   CellFormat cellformat1 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 0 };
   CellFormat cellformat2 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 49 };
```

Now `cellformat1`can be used for general cells and `cellformat2` can be used for forced string cells.

So when you try to extract format code in a general cell, it might return null since `NumberFormatId` is not set or **0** if number format is set to general type.

This explains why you get correct id for number formatted cells but not for general cells.

Comment: Yes I know this is the reason Number format cells are working, but I need to figure out why the General Format cells are returning wrong Cell FormatId and how to make it to match the correct/intended one.

Comment: @pnuts null or 0 is the NumberFormatID that he is mentioning, not the Cell FormatID

Comment: General format type are not specific. they are like default. Try changing cell format by right clicking on any cell in excel .